# How to enable a BOT on my website with rich text messages(Quick replies, cards etc) embedded on it?

Tags: web, dialogflow-es

I need to integrate a bot on my website. Api.ai bot supports rich messages on social media messengers like facebook etc. 
Is there any way to do the same for my own website?

Comment: Api.ai seems to have embed support, at least they have samples for Webkit HTML5. If you don't need api.ai specifically, I think Microsoft's Bot Framework supports embedding on websites as well. What is your problem, specifically? What have you tried?

Comment: @koneke Api.ai does support embedding on websites. But messages can only be textual. I want my bot on website to send rich text messages that includes carousels, quick replies etc. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Okay, so does it *have* to be api.ai? Because if that's the case, there seems like there's no easy way of getting it working as far as I can see. If not, have you looked at Microsoft's one?

Comment: I have once used Microsoft's bot but the response time is quite slow :/

Comment: Alright, but again, does it *need* to be api.ai, or are other alternatives an option? If it needs to be api.ai, I guess you could see if it's possible to embed one of the clients it does support right messages for. I haven't worked with api.ai specifically before, but could you do something like embedding a slack chat window or something?

Comment: No it is not necessarily to be Api.ai but yes that would be preferable. Yes api.ai does support rich messages for facebook. i have deployed one over there but now i need to deploy the bot my website too... Should i go for another framework for that?

Comment: Well, if you already have it deployed with api.ai, I'd stay with that. I'd take a look at which clients api.ai can talk to, and see if one of those are easily embeddable onto a website. Take a look at https://docs.api.ai/docs/integrations

Comment: But i dont want to integrate it on social media platforms. i want to integrate it on my website with rich messages format whether by api.ai or by another platform that can help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to do a bit of coding:

- Build a chat ui,
- call your own server ..
- ...that will call api.ai via REST
- and then render everything that you want, based on the action that api.ai did figure out for you.